# How to locate files/directories in Windows power shell

Tags: windows, windows-shell

I am using a remote windows server and  I have access to only windows power shell. I need to find path of few directories. Is there any way to locate files/directories in windows power shell.

Thank You

Comment: This is a pretty trivial question which could be easily answered by reading the documentation. Have you tried using [IO.Directory]::GetFiles("c:\") or even DIR? Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: "Dir" is not working because then I have to go to each directory and type DIR command. If I am searching for Mysql should I write like [IO.MySql] =GetFiles("c:\"). If yes, its not working!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, the command is

```
C:\> get-childitem -recurse -include *directory-name*
```